# Runtime Exception while launching android app

Tags: android

I was trying to launch my android application from eclipse, but whenever I launch the application, it gets stuck and I receive the following error in the LogCat

```
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        instantiate application com.iiitd.muc.mobishare.c: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iiitd.muc.mobishare.c in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.iiitd.muc.mobishare-2.apk]
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3264)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iiitd.muc.mobishare.c in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.iiitd.muc.mobishare-2.apk]
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
12-15 22:04:03.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
```

Some more background:
I am basically trying to add this library in my application. http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

as mentioned in the instructions, I have added this line of code in the onCreate method of my application.

```
LocationLibrary.initialiseLibrary(getBaseContext(), 60 * 1000, 2 * 60 * 1000, "mobi.littlefluffytoys.littlefluffytestclient");
```

which is causing an error. If I remove this line of code, the app runs fine.

Can someone help me resolving this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove that line everything works? Is the library proguard'ed? Are you sure the library is being included in your APK? Post your application class code, and your manifest please

Comment: Something was not right with the Manifest.xml, I changed it back to some previous version and now it working fine. This line: `<application android:name=".TestApplication" android:label="@string/app_name">` was the issue. The name had to be .TestApplication, and previously it was "c"

Comment: @RobertEstivill: Even after removing the initialiseLibrary() function, the code didnt work. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is the step you are missing from the library docs --

> To use the library, add littlefluffylocationlibrary.jar as an external
>   JAR into your Android project. In Eclipse, this is easiest done by
>   creating a folder in your project called libs, copying the file into
>   it, refresh the project, right-click the .jar file, and then select
>   Add to build path.

Verify that you copied the jar file to your libs directory and that it is in your build path (this is done automatically on later versions of the ADT)

Comment: Yes. That also helped. I was not copying the files into the lib folder which also caused issues. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still face this issue , as on 1-Dec-2015,

little-fluffy-location-library does not work with newer versions of Google Play Services. The application will crash with ClassNotFoundException if used with newer versions of Google Play Location Services.

Google Play Services version 6.1 works fine for me. If you are using Gradle to build your project, add this to your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Main cause is "Class Not Found"
So ,At first You Shoul Check current path of source code.

and also check property off project that your  are running correct project or not.